# mozilla, trouble changing first css style with 2nd new style

Tags: css, firefox, mozilla

[This](http://www.dungeoncrawler.com/adventures/index.html) is a pretty basic page, but I'm having issues with it displaying properly in `Mozilla/Firefox`.  Works fine in `Chrome` and `IE`.

It's a php page, which I don't believe is the issue.  The page has a primary style sheet for the overall site which is main.css, and a sub-style page which loads 2nd and should overwrite what I need/want changed called adv.css FF doesn't seem to want to read adv.css

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache or opening a private tab/window?

Comment: Yep, that seems to have worked.  *sigh*  Thank you!

Comment: No problem.  Hang in there!  :)  I added an answer that could prove useful to you to help avoid caching.  Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like it was a caching problem.  Here's a little trick you can use to avoid caching, using PHP:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/adv.css?v=<?php echo date("Ymd.H.i.s", filemtime("/css/adv.css")); ?>" />
```

That way, every time you make a modification to your CSS, you'll get an automatic new version on your CSS file(s).

**Edit:** As Mike suggests in the comments, an even better way would be to disable cache while dev tools are open.

To do this on Chrome or Firefox:

1. Hit F12
2. Click the little gear for Settings
3. - (Chrome) In the General tab, check the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"
   - (Firefox) In the Advanced Settings, check the "Disable Cache (when toolbox is open)"

Comment: This is a great trick I use often, but make sure you don't deploy this into production.  Only use in a development environment.  Caching is a good thing.

Comment: You are correct - caching is an excellent thing in production.  Of course, this  code will keep the CSS cached as long as you don't change it because it uses a timestamp.  However, you'll probably have a slight performance improvement by removing the PHP anyway.  :)

Comment: Oops... you are right.  I read it differently.  I usually just echo the date/time at the moment in development to trigger a new server request.  You are doing it one step better.  I remember trying it this way once, and something in my server was blocking access to the filemtime, or something like that, so I started doing it the simpler way.  Now I just use Grunt/Sass/browser refresh.  No more php for me.  :)

Comment: or don't do that, and instead do your dev work with the dev tools open and "disable cache while dev tools are open" turned on. That way you don't have to write cachebusting timestamp codes that might make it to production (all webkit browsers, as well as Firefox, have this option)

Comment: Thanks, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans!  I updated my answer with that.